# Median and Mean Household Income at the County Level back to 1990

Tags: income

Interested in measuring the spread between the median and mean household income in New York County (aka Manhattan) going back to 1990. Where can I get median and mean household income at the county level going back 20 years?

**Sources I've found:**

Here is median income for NY State for that time period:
http://www.statista.com/statistics/205974/median-household-income-in-new-york/

ACS has this info, but only back to ~2009:
https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?pid=ACS_14_5YR_S1901&prodType=table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1990 Census of Population: Social and Economic Characteristics (page 410)
http://www2.census.gov/library/publications/decennial/1990/cp-2/cp-2-34-1.pdf

Table QT-P32 Income Distribution in 1999 of Households and Families: 2000, Census 2000 Summary File 3 (SF 3) - Sample Data
http://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/DEC/00_SF3/QTP32/0400000US36.05000

2009-2014 earnings in last 12 months:
http://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?pid=ACS_14_5YR_S1901&prodType=table

Answer (score 2):

Estimate-based data for mean and median household income at the county level is available for: 1990, 2000, 2005-2009, 2006-2010, 2007-2011, 2008-2012, 2009-2013, 2010-2014 ( and 2011-2015 in Dec. 2016). [American Factfinder](http://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml) is a good resource for these estimates. [NHGIS](https://data2.nhgis.org/review) is a good resource for processed Census data that is GIS-friendly.

Model-based data for median household income at the county level is available through [SAIPE](http://www.census.gov/did/www/saipe/data/statecounty/data/index.html).